# Why is it in set not in function doesn't work properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

```
def anagram(s):
    if(len(s)%2==1):
        return -1
    counter = 0
    s1 = s[:len(s)//2]
    s2 = s[len(s)//2:]
    s1,s2 = set(s1),set(s2)
    print(s1)
    print(s2)
    if s1 not in s2:
        counter = counter + 1

    return counter

print(anagram("xyyx"))
```

Output:

```
{'x', 'y'}
{'x', 'y'}
1
```

I'm supposed to get 0 as x and y both are present in the sets s1 and s2. can anyone help with the problem I'm facing

Comment: the `not in` is working *exactly as it is documented to work for sets*. Why do you think `s1 not in s2` is supposed to do that?

Comment: The set `s1` is not present in the set `s2`.  Indeed, the set `s2` does not contain any sets at all.  Do you see the problem?  Sets are not the right way to solve this problem anyway.  Consider the line "abbcabcc".  Your code would call those anagrams.  You just need to sort the strings and compare the sorted versions.

Comment: @TimRoberts so, `collections.Counter(s1) == collections.Counter(s2)` would work, since basically, it is multi-set equality.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga -- That would work, but it's overkill.  Just sort the string halves and compare them for equality.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm not sure what you mean by "overkill". Seems more like the easiest, most straightforward solution (that also happens to be the most efficient, albeit, that probably isn't a big concern). But yeah, basically the same effort as `sorted(s1) == sorted(s2)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are checking for inequality just use !=. Currently you are checking to see if s1 is within s2.

```
if s1 != s2:
    counter = counter + 1
```

Output:

```
{'x', 'y'}
{'x', 'y'}
0
```